# What does the Age such as "10m (x64 over 24h)" mean in k8s events?

Tags: events, kubernetes, concept

What does the Age such as "10m (x64 over 24h)" mean in k8s events?

e.g.

```yaml
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                 From                                   Message
  ----     ------     ----                ----                                   -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  10m (x64 over 24h)  kubelet, worker-pool1-9a9436te-ccdamf  Readiness probe failed: Get http://192.168.177.153:8088/readiness: dial tcp 192.168.177.153:8088: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Pulled     10m (x9 over 27h)   kubelet, worker-pool1-9a9436te-ccdamf  Container image "k8s-registry.local/image/image1:1.100.0-51" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    10m (x9 over 27h)   kubelet, worker-pool1-9a9436te-ccdamf  Created container mm-controller
```

Does it healthy now or not?
from description:

```yaml
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True
```

It seems to be `Ready`, but since there is no time stamps, I am confused.

Answer (score 4):

`10m (x64 over 24h)` means the last time this event happened 10 minutes ago and this event has occurred 64 times over a period of last 24h.

Pod is ready to serve traffic as the `Ready` is true. `Conditions` just shows the latest status.

Readiness probe will succeed once the app is running and kubernetes is able to validate it by hitting the endpoint defined in readiness probe. Now the app may take sometime to actually run and readiness probe will fail till that time.

You can provide a `initialDelaySeconds` to avoid that.

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Should I expect another `Readiness` probe failure, and the Age becoming "xxm ( x65 over 24h)" in about 20min if nothing has changed?

Comment: readiness probe can succeed once the app is running and it may take some time for that app to be running..you will see readiness probe failed till then

Comment: I am searching for the official explain from K8s/google. But it seems they assume to understand that is by default. Thanks for the answer.